# Android best piano organ layout

Tags: android, layout, touch, piano

My app has a background image of a music organ and I have used `LinearLayout`s with `Button`s with their backgrounds set to `@null` to act as keys.

I've implemented my layout with `View.OnTouchListener` and in `OnTouch` I play the relevant sound on `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and stop it on `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`.

This sort of works fine except that when I slide my fingers across the buttons (organ keys) due to them being buttons (I think) no new ontouch event are triggered unless I lift and retouch on a button.

Can anyone suggest a better layout that uses some other control perhaps that would enable me to detect a slide across them to achieve the slide up or down keyboard effect?

I don't really want to draw they keys from scratch as I want to utilise the graphics in the background image (for the organ keyboard) that is more pleasing than drawn rectangles.
Thanks

```
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/vibrato_off" android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="95" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".main">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="70"></LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llblack" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="11">
    <View android:layout_width="1dp" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1.5"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/vib_off" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <View android:layout_width="1dp" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="0.4"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/a2u" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.5" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/a2sharp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/b2u" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.5" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/c3u" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.5" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/c3sharp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/d3sharp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/e3u" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.5" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/f3u" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.5" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/f3sharp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/g3sharp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/a3sharp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/b3u" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.5" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/c4u" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.5" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/c4sharp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/d4sharp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/e4u" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.5" android:background="@null"/>
    <View android:layout_width="1dp" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llwhite" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="9">
    <View android:layout_width="1dp" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="1.5"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/vib_on" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <View android:layout_width="1dp" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="0.4"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/a2" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/b2" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/c3" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/d3" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/e3" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/f3" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/g3" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/a3" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/b3" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/c4" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/d4" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <android.view.View android:id="@+id/e4" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@null"/>
    <View android:layout_width="1dp" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="0.4"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No Maths, I'm using the layout to determine the positions of the views which lay directly over the correct organ keys on the background image. I'm using layout weights so that on different size screens the views will be over the correct keys. Do you know of a way to calculate something similar without using views and instead some maths on the whole linear layout that would hopefully make slide work utilising action_move?

Comment: Due to the non standard musical keyboard layout that was not full width it was difficult to calc key positions. In the end I kept the layout including buttons or views, doesnt seem to make any difference and in ontouch I looped through all child views checking ontouch XY to Rect.contains of child views until it matched. Then using the tag of the view I knew which sample to play. Adding ACTION_MOVE then overcame original issue which allows the user to slide across organ keys. Thanks goes to Zabri for his help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're doing some math to know where to put the buttons so that they correspondent with the background image.

If you set an `OnTouchListener` to the whole `LinearLayout` and implement it to do stuff on `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`, you could use the same math to figure out where the user has touched the `LinearLayout` to know which key he or she actually intended to press. So you don't need buttons at all.

Then you would implement the listener to also do something on `ACTION_MOVE` and with the help of the math you're already doing, you could figure out when the user has left one key with his or her finger and moved to a different one. So you'd basically compare current coordinates of the finger to its coordinates when the `onTouch()` method was previously called, so you'd know to which key the movement went so that you can start playing its sound, and also from which key it went so you can stop playing the sound of the previous one. If the movement started and ended on the same key, you do nothing.

I did a similar thing about a year ago when I was implementing a calendar where the user could select an interval by sliding from one of the calendar cells to another. And the calendar had to update as the user was sliding, so I also had to know when he or she left one cell and moved the finger to another. So I am sure, that if you implement it correctly, it will work.

I assume, since it's supposed to be an app simulating a piano, that you need to allow the user to slide the keyboard not only with one, but with two (or more) fingers, right? I think this should also be easily possible because the `MotionEvent` carries information about the pointer (finger, mouse pointer, ...) that did the motion. I don't have any experience with that though, but you could read more about it at the `MotionEvent` documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Hope it helps. If you have further questions, I'd be happy to answer (also more concretely - I still have the calendar's code.)

Good luck.

**EDIT to answer the comment:**

I didn't mean using `View`s instead of `Button`s. I meant your layout to consist only of a `LinearLayout` with the background image set to it. And that's it. Then in code, you attach an `OnTouchListener` to it and in the `onTouch()` method, you calculate the position. Off the top of my head, I think you could do it like this:

I assume the app should be used in a landscape mode and that the image of the piano covers the whole screen. Let’s say you have 8 white piano keys on it. By dividing the screen width by 8, you know how wide one piano key is on the device. You also know where one key starts and where it ends. Let’s say one key is 50 px wide. Then the first one starts on the 1st px and ends on the 50th. The second one starts on the 51st and ends on the 100th. And so on.

So then, if the touch event happens, you can access its coordinates by calling `MotionEvent.getX` or `MotionEvent.getY`. Now I don't know if you need `getX` or `getY`, you have to figure that out. So let's say that method returns a number like 94. When you divide it by your previously calculated piano key width, and round the result up to the nearest integer, you'll know which key the user pressed. So if the width is 50, you do 94 / 50 = 1.88, round it up to 2 and you have the 2nd key.

And you should store the `getX`/`getY` variable in your activity, so that when you detect the next event, you can tell what happened. So if you get an `ACTION_DOWN` on the 2nd key and then you get an `ACTION_MOVE` and you calculate it to actually already be on the 3rd key, you know the user has pressed the 2nd key and then slided to the 3rd key. So you stop playing 2nd key's sound and start playing the 3rd's one.

I hope it makes sense and that it's not a too primitive and stupid approach. :)

Comment: Great idea, OnTouchListener on the LinearLayout and not on buttons... going to change code now.. thanks for the informative reply.

Comment: If it helped you, I would also be glad if you could accept the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Currently using the position of the buttons in the linear layouts to determine, in ontouch, the part of the layout that was pressed. Tried you idea of using the whole layout instead of buttons but cannot figure a way to calculate the position pressed relative to the background image containing the organ keys. Also tried using view instead of button but MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE still not triggered when view is already pressed. I will add my current layout to question to give you an idea of the layout. Perhaps you may have an idea how to overcome issues...

Comment: Thanks I'm trying something similar at the moment. Need to do more calcs as keys do not fill entire width (landscape) so cant just divide by number of keys. The keys also do not fill entire height so also need more calcs. That's why I initially went down the button route. thanks